# Capitalising after punctuation within speech?

Tags: style, technique, novel, punctuation

I've notices that Emily Bronte does not always capitalise in dialogue after exclamation marks or question marks, for example (light spoilers):

> "Be with me always - take any form - drive me mad! only do not leave me in this abyss, where I cannot find you!"

> "Persuade him! speak of your own mind: say you are certain I will!"

This does not appear to be a quirk of editions.

Why do you think Bronte does this? It seems to occur in "stream of consciousness moments." Do you know any other authors who use this style? And most importantly, do you think this technique is appropriate in contemporary writing?

Comment: Why do *you* think she's done this? Do you think it has the effect she wanted? Is it an effect that you want to copy? That's the only real question here.

Comment: This is discussed in various places on English Language and Usage SE, such as https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/353214/should-i-capitalize-after-an-exclamation-in-dialogue Basically, it's commoner in older texts, particularly in dialog.

Comment: @StuartF Thank you, I couldn't find it in my search. That answers my question.